# How isolate a certain number of characters after a string in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this very ridiculous string (see below) and want to strip it from all useless information.

I want to isolate all information that looks like that:

```
 Deal: -139.8 | normal: 228.27 | new: 88.47 | CGN - BCN (Sep 25, Sep 27)
```

Numbers here can all be different, and so can the airport codes (CGN and BCN). The length of the string can also be different. Instead of just having

```
CGN - BCN (Sep 25, Sep 27)
```

in the end, there could be

```
CGN - BCN (Sep 25), BCN - NYC (Sep 27)
```

EDIT: How can I use a regex to isolate those information? I've started with `[Deal\:\s\-]` to indicate that the string should start with this. Then I simply got lost. Since I am super new to regex and I did not know how to proceed from here

```
' ˇˇˇˇ304688Rv0OhVyeiV74 <>‘bD$æ⁄    Deal: -1811.28 | normal: 3158.15 | new: 1346.87 | TXL - NYC (Mar 18), NYC - ATL (Mar 24), ATL - MSY (Mar 30), MSY - TXL (Apr 02)UçÒˇˇˇ¸Uçıˇˇˇˇ304687 <>œ‘vh∞æ⁄    Deal: -319.59 | normal: 624.67 | new: 305.08 | SIN - DUS (Apr 28)UåÕºˇˇˇ¸UåÕøˇˇˇˇ303965lRaD7YP70KR+<team@new.com>œ‘ä√æ⁄    Deal: -319.52 | normal: 624.55 | new: 305.03 | SIN - DUS (Apr 28)UåÕçˇˇˇ¸UåÕëˇˇˇˇ303966s4Z+<team@new.com>œ‘ù€µæ⁄    Deal: -322.71 | normal: 627.58 | new: 304.87 | SIN - DUS (May 05)Uå¬zˇˇˇ¸Uå¬~ˇˇˇˇ304686 <team@new.com>’‘±êÕæ⁄    Deal: -139.8 | normal: 228.27 | new: 88.47 | CGN - BCN (Sep 25, Sep 27)UåÅØˇˇˇ¸UåÅ≤ˇˇˇˇ3039613//TlCzBs/<>œ‘≈]µæŸ    Deal: -381.52 | normal: 732.66 | new: 351.14 | CGN - PEK (Aug 10)UåaGˇˇˇ¸UåaKˇˇˇˇ303962lWWb2SgeIy+<>œ‘Ÿ∏æŸ    Deal: -148.04 | normal: 293.55 | new: 145.51 | BER - LPA (Oct 17)UåT!'
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the data once you have isolated it?  I would probably try splitting the string multiple times before resorting to regex.

Comment: Sounds fair enough to do that. I'll use it to analyze the data with an excel file I have. So separating all the "Deals" would be a good start. I could start a new line before each deal?

Comment: *I've started with [Deal\:\s\-]*. Please read up carefully on character sets and what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is fixed ,you can use

```
\bDeal:.*?\([^|]*\)
```

and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/55

```
var re = /\bDeal:.*?\([^|]*\)/gm; 
var str = '\' ˇˇˇˇ304688Rv0OhVyeiV74 <>‘bD$æ⁄    Deal: -1811.28 | normal: 3158.15 | new: 1346.87 | TXL - NYC (Mar 18), NYC - ATL (Mar 24), ATL - MSY (Mar 30), MSY - TXL (Apr 02)UçÒˇˇˇ¸Uçıˇˇˇˇ304687 <>œ‘vh∞æ⁄    Deal: -319.59 | normal: 624.67 | new: 305.08 | SIN - DUS (Apr 28)UåÕºˇˇˇ¸UåÕøˇˇˇˇ303965lRaD7YP70KR+<team@new.com>œ‘ä√æ⁄    Deal: -319.52 | normal: 624.55 | new: 305.03 | SIN - DUS (Apr 28)UåÕçˇˇˇ¸UåÕëˇˇˇˇ303966s4Z+<team@new.com>œ‘ù€µæ⁄    Deal: -322.71 | normal: 627.58 | new: 304.87 | SIN - DUS (May 05)Uå¬zˇˇˇ¸Uå¬~ˇˇˇˇ304686 <team@new.com>’‘±êÕæ⁄    Deal: -139.8 | normal: 228.27 | new: 88.47 | CGN - BCN (Sep 25, Sep 27)UåÅØˇˇˇ¸UåÅ≤ˇˇˇˇ3039613//TlCzBs/<>œ‘≈]µæŸ    Deal: -381.52 | normal: 732.66 | new: 351.14 | CGN - PEK (Aug 10)UåaGˇˇˇ¸UåaKˇˇˇˇ303962lWWb2SgeIy+<>œ‘Ÿ∏æŸ    Deal: -148.04 | normal: 293.55 | new: 145.51 | BER - LPA (Oct 17)UåT!\'';
var subst = ''; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: how can I make sure to isolate everything EXCEPT the above term?

Comment: @user3383709 after you do replaceyou will get everything except the above term